# Sending POST request to another domain from an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, http-post

I have gone through most of the threads on SE treating similar problems to this one, none so far was able to help me with my problem. but If I'm mistaken and another thread does answer my question, please me to it.

In my website I have a web page with an Iframe which loads a contact form from one of many websites, and fills automatically the data in the form using a JS script.

First problem occurs here, If I run chrome without --disable-web-security the field won't be filled and the JS won't be executed, but if I fill those fields manually and submit the form it works.

But when I run Chrome with the --disable-web-security flag the fields will be filled, but submitting the form just refreshes the page. and sometimes a "Javascript has to be activated" error message pops up

The optimal solution would be to find a way to fill the script and submit it without having to run chrome with any flag.

PS : web app is in Java (Jetty)

Comment: Please provide what you have tried and make a [fiddle](jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mzs8busz/3/) enough ?